Find average rate per group in specific years using groupby transform
I'm trying to find a better/faster way to do this. I have a rather large dataset (~200M rows) with individual dates per row. I want to find the average yearly rate per group from 2018 to 2019. I know I could create a small df with the results and merge it back in but, I was trying to find a way to use transform. Not sure if it would just be faster to merge. Extra points for one-liners.
Sample data
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':rng.choice(list('ABCD'), 100),
                   'date':[(pd.to_datetime('2018')+pd.Timedelta(days=x)).normalize() for x in rng.integers(0, 365*5, 100)],
                   'foo':rng.integers(1, 100, 100),
                   'bar':rng.integers(50, 200, 100)})
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year

This works
#find average 2018 and 2019 'foo' and 'bar'
for col in ['foo', 'bar']:
    for y in [2018, 2019]:
        df[col+'_'+str(y)+'_total'] = df.groupby('group')['year'].transform(lambda x: df.loc[x.where(x==y).dropna().index, col].sum())

#find 2018 and 2019 rates
for y in [2018, 2019]:
    df['rate_'+str(y)] =  df['foo_'+str(y)+'_total'].div(df['bar_'+str(y)+'_total'])

#find average rate
df['2018_2019_avg_rate'] = df[['rate_2018', 'rate_2019']].mean(axis=1)

Thing's I've tried that don't quite work (I'm using apply to test if it works before switching to transform)
#gives yearly totals for each year and each column, but further 'apply'ing to find rates then averaging isn't working after I switch to transform
df.groupby(['group', 'year'])['year'].apply(lambda x: df.loc[x.where(x.between(2018, 2019)).dropna().index, ['foo', 'bar']].sum())

#close but is averaging too early
df.groupby(['group', 'year'])['year'].apply(lambda x: df.loc[i, 'foo'].sum()/denom if (denom:=df.loc[i:=x.where(x.between(2018, 2019)).dropna().index, 'bar'].sum())>0 else np.nan)


You can't perform multiple filtering/aggregations efficiently with a groupby.transform. You will have to loop.
A more efficient approach would be to combine a pivot_table + merge:
cols = ['foo', 'bar']
years = [2018, 2019]

tmp = (df[df['year'].isin(years)]
       .pivot_table(index='group', columns='year',
                    values=cols, aggfunc='sum')
       [cols]
       .pipe(lambda x: x.join(pd.concat({'rate': x['foo'].div(x['bar'])}, axis=1)))
      )

avg_rate = tmp['rate'].mean(axis=1)

tmp.columns = tmp.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}_total')

tmp[f'{"_".join(map(str, years))}_avg_rate'] = avg_rate

out = df.merge(tmp, left_on='group', right_index=True)

Output:
   group       date  foo  bar  year  foo_2018_total  foo_2019_total  bar_2018_total  bar_2019_total  rate_2018_total  rate_2019_total  2018_2019_avg_rate
0      A 2022-03-11   59   91  2022             343             270             972             875         0.352881         0.308571            0.330726
1      C 2018-08-22   56   52  2018             175             325             331             902         0.528701         0.360310            0.444506
2      C 2019-04-24   47   89  2019             175             325             331             902         0.528701         0.360310            0.444506
3      A 2019-04-16   43  102  2019             343             270             972             875         0.352881         0.308571            0.330726
4      D 2019-11-25    3   56  2019             126             222             224             696         0.562500         0.318966            0.440733
5      A 2018-01-06   86  148  2018             343             270             972             875         0.352881         0.308571            0.330726
...
99     B 2018-02-25   32   90  2018             253             204             703             400         0.359886         0.510000            0.434943


My test shows that this is not significantly faster than OP's approach.

@QuangHoang how have you tested? OP said they have a very large number of rows. The gain in efficiency will depend on the number of groups. If there are few groups with a large number of rows, I'd expect to see a gain.

I used OP's sample data, with size 10K and 100K.

From my testing this answer is faster for a variety of sample sizes from 100 to 1M rows. See my answer for brief details. Are you sure you didn't also time the dataframe generation process? This was far slower than the data wrangling itself in my case.

An approach using transform:
mask_year = df['year'].isin([2018, 2019])

df.loc[mask_year, 'foo_total'] = df[mask_year].groupby(['group', 'year'])['foo'].transform('sum')
df.loc[mask_year, 'bar_total'] = df[mask_year].groupby(['group', 'year'])['bar'].transform('sum')

df['rate'] = df['foo_total'] / df['bar_total']
df.loc[:, '2018_2019_avg_rate'] = df.groupby(['group'])['rate'].transform(lambda x: np.nanmean(x.unique()))

From my limited testing, this is slightly slower than @mozway's answer.
For 1 million rows of sample data, average execution time on my laptop over 100 runs:

OP's approach: 0.76 seconds
Mozway's approach: 0.23 seconds
This approach: 0.29 seconds

